# How Do I layout Function Prototypes mixing C with C++

Tags: c++, c, name-mangling, extern-c

I have a header that I want to include from .c and .cpp files.

so I know about name mangling and extern "C" so...

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
    int isPrime(int64_t p);
}
#endif
```

but when I include this in the .c file it doesn't see the function because of the `#ifdef __cplusplus`

so then I end up making 2 copies:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"
    {
        int isPrime(int64_t p);
    }
 #else
     int isPrime(int64_t p);
 #endif
```

is there a better way to do this... I thought about making another header called prototypes.h and including that in those 2 places... but is there something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way. People are usually doing this :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
    int isPrime(int64_t p);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

---

If you want to do something different in c and c++ (like for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14937055/476681)) then you can use the 2nd syntax in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Another way of doing this is as follows

```
// intro
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERN_C extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERN_C
#endif

// content
EXTERN_C int isPrime(int64_t p);
// many other functions declared with EXTERN_C
```

Normally the "intro" part is placed in some common header file for everyone to use.

The advantage of this format is that each declaration is immediately seen as `extern "C"`. A reader doesn't have to search around for possible `extern "C" {`

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"
    {
 #endif
        int isPrime(int64_t p);
#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
 #endif
```

That way, you can extend the `int isPrime(int64_t p);` part arbitrarily without repeating it in your `#ifdef` and  `#else` cases.