# Trouble compiling/linking C and C++ files

Tags: c++, c, makefile, linker

I have tried searching around other questions here on SO, but have still been unable to get my newly created C++ and `.h` linked to my main C file correctly. My implementation of my `loader.cpp` and `loader.h` are based off of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917952/can-i-use-shared-library-created-in-c-in-a-c-program).

My `loader.cpp` has no `main` function as I just want to use the C++ functions there. My `shift.c` file is where my `int main()` is located. Here is the basic structure of my `loader.cpp` file.

#### loader.cpp

```
#include "loader.h"
...
// Class Declaration
...
// Class implementation
```

I have been trying to compile with the following.

`g++ loader.cpp -o obj -lGLU -lGL -lglut`

The error I am getting here is...

```
(.text+0x20): undefined reference `to main'
```

So my two questions are, how do I get my cpp file to compile properly, and then what do I need to add to my `Makefile` to link them properly?

#### Makefile (for reference)

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++

EXE = shift gears

# Main target
all: $(EXE)

CFLG=-O3 -Wall
LIBS=-lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm

CLEAN=rm -f $(EXE) *.o *.a


# Dependencies
gears.o: gears.c
shift.o: shift.c CSCIx229.h
fatal.o: fatal.c CSCIx229.h
loadtexbmp.o: loadtexbmp.c CSCIx229.h
print.o: print.c CSCIx229.h
project.o: project.c CSCIx229.h
errcheck.o: errcheck.c CSCIx229.h
object.o: object.c CSCIx229.h

#  Create archive
CSCIx229.a:fatal.o loadtexbmp.o print.o project.o errcheck.o object.o
    ar -rcs $@ $^

# Compile rules
.c.o:
    gcc -c $(CFLG) $<
.cpp.o:
    g++ -c $(CFLG) $<

#  Link
shift:shift.o CSCIx229.a
    gcc -O3 -o $@ $^   $(LIBS)

gears:gears.o
    gcc -O3 -o $@ $^   $(LIBS)

#  Clean
clean:
    $(CLEAN)
```

Comment: Which file contains your `main` function?  The error is because you are trying to create an executable without a `main`.

Comment: My `c` file, which is named `shift.c`

Comment: You need to add your `shift.o` file to the linker command line.

Comment: The `.cpp.o` rule you have in your makefile there has the key bit you are missing. Did you write that `g++` line that isn't working by hand? Does `make loader.o` work right now?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't believe the OP is trying to create the exe there. I believe they are trying to create `loader.o` (though why it is being called `obj` there I'm not sure).

Comment: Change your make rule for the linker to use `g++`, not `gcc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `g++` to compile an object module without linking it into a complete program then you must give it the `-c` option:

```
g++ -c loader.cpp -o loader.o
```

Note that that compilation command also assigns a conventional name to the generated object file, and that if you're not linking it into an executable then you don't need to specify libraries to link it to.  Your `Makefile` is already set up for this.

If you add `loader.o` to the dependencies of `CSCIx229.a` then that should be enough to persuade `make` to build it from `loader.cpp` and to include the object file in your library (which will make it available for linking into your executables).  You may also need to add some or all of `-lGLU -lGL -lglut` to your `LIBS` variable.  It might also be appropriate to add `loader.o`'s dependencies to the makefile if they include more than just `loader.cpp` itself (e.g. if they include `CSCIx229.h`).

Comment: Right. The tl;dr version here is "treat `loader.o` the way you treat the other `.o` files you are using in that library and it should Just Work".

Answer (score 0):

Add the -c option to compile only.  When you are ready to link the final application, then include all the object files and the list of libraries.

```
g++ -c loader.cpp -o loader.o
g++ loader.o (and the rest of your object files)  -lGLU -lGL -lglut
```

Try adding this to your makefile:

```
shift:shift.o CSCIx229.a loader.o
    gcc -O3 -o $@ $^   $(LIBS)
```